# How can you define something to happen and remain in that state?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a game in jquery in which if you press right key on the keyboard it loads a certain image and if you press left key on the keyboard it loads another image . My problem is that all of this is happening in an interval that keeps repeating . As soon as the program finds that my right key is no longer pressed it will automatically draw the second Image.  I want it to do the following :
- if I press right arrow, it will draw the Image1 and remain in that state until I press the left key
-if I press left arrow, I want my Image2 to be drawn and remain in that state until I press the right key

If I do this in a while loop my web page will crash because it will stay in that while loop and what follows won t be executed .

This is working, but as soon as I release the right key, rightDown will be false and when the program finds the if statement again it will draw my Image2 . (the interval is really fast)

```
if(rightDown)drawImage1();
else drawImage2();
```

If I use this

```
if(rightDown)drawImage1();
else if(leftDown) drawImage2();
```

and I don t press the left or right key no image will be drawn.

rightDown and leftDown

```
function onKeyDown(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode == 39) rightDown = true;
  else if (evt.keyCode == 37) leftDown = true;
  else if (evt.keyCode == 38) upKeyDown = true;
  else if(evt.keyCode == 40)  downKeyDown = true;
}
```

and the part when they are not clicked

```
function onKeyUp(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode == 39) rightDown = false;
  else if (evt.keyCode == 37) leftDown = false;
  else if (evt.keyCode == 38) upKeyDown = false;
  else if (evt.keyCode == 40) downKeyDown = false;
}
```

$(document).keydown(onKeyDown);
$(document).keyup(onKeyUp);

Comment: Show us more of your code...the relevant parts. How are you getting `rightDown`?

Comment: sidebar - look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame to mitigate your performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a function to draw your default image, named `drawDefault()`; using this code:

```
window.onload = drawDefault;
```

Such that, upon the window's loading, it will draw the default picture (can also be used as `window.onload = drawImage[1,2]();` (where [...] denotes choice).

If you have already defined a `.onload` method for `window`, then you can simply extend your `.onload` function:

```
window.onload = function(){
    // ... code ...
    drawDefault();
}
```

Or, with a more interesting way:

```
if(!window.onload){
    window.onload = drawDefault;
} else {
    var on = window.onload;
    window.onload = function(){
        on();
        drawDefault();
    }
}
```

Combined with this, use your code:

```
if(rightDown)drawImage1();
else if(leftDown) drawImage2();
```

(Personally, I'd used `{...}` to enclose `if`, `else if`, and `else` statements, as it's easier to read (and how hard is it to press two extra keys or such?).

The outcome will be, if I have interpreted both your question and your code (what there was of it, anyhow) correctly, what will happen is that:

1. The default image will be displayed
2. On `rightDown`, the right image will be displayed, and,
3. On `leftDown`, the left image will be displayed.

Hope it helps!!